# How do split damage abilities work if someone is immune to damage in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

https://www.wowhead.com/spell=299914/frenetic-charge

Here is an example of a split damage ability.

"After 6 sec, he charges to the player, inflicting 864871 Frost damage, split between all players within 8 yards of the target and knocking them back."

So if you have 2 players soaking, each will take around 430k damage.

If one of the players is immune to damage, will the damage still be split but 1 person takes nothing? Or since that person is immune to damage, will 1 player take everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base damage is split between each player in the affected area. This damage is then individually processed for each player with regards to immunities, damage reduction effects, absorbs and increased damage taken events. So any active immunities cut a sizeable chunk out of the damage the healers need to heal.

The core logic behind this is that determining who takes the damage doesn't happen at the same time as determining how much damage each player takes. The game isn't going to mess around with slightly shifting damage from one player to another in order to ensure that all players take their fair share of damage. That would totally defeat the point of having damage reduction effects active on players.

Comment: True, that is what I think would happen as well. I am curious though if there is a difference between damage reduction and being immune to damage. Since the player is immune, its plausible that they are not considered in the share of damage. But I wasn't 100% sure. Do you know for certain this is how it works in WoW?

Comment: @Childishforlife This is how it works in WoW. Blizzard tries VERY hard in avoiding counterintuitive game mechanics where doing an illogical thing would actually be preferable. They don't want players to end up in a situation where they think they are doing the right thing, like using an immunity effect or a crowd control effect, but they end up actively harming the raid instead. If abilities don't work like this, they're explicitly mentioned like that in the dungeon journal, or it's a special effect for the hardest bosses in the game.

Answer (score 0):

## Most likely how this would work is that it takes the total damage, divides it by the number of targets, and *then* deals that much damage to each.

To use your example The user of the ability activates it, then the game does the math. It sees there are two valid targets within the range of the effect. It looks at the total damage the ability does, in this case 865k (rounded) and divides that by the number of targets it found. 865k/2 = 432.5k damage assigned to each target. Player one is immune to Frost damage and loses no health to the effect but still "takes" his allotted 432k damage. Player two is not immune and loses the normal amount of health to the effect due to the damage.

Comment: That was my logic as well! But I am looking for a concrete answer relating to World of Warcraft.

Comment: @Childishforlife I see. I can't give a concrete answer on my own but I will check a few sources I have and update my answer with whatever information I find from current players

Comment: In WoW, that would work for most boss skills - but not all of them. Some require taking damage and immunity would do nothing and eventually kill the other player(s). Mitigating damage is always fine, though. So the best answer for this questions is: it depends.